# How to make sprite-images change on hover different items?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a `sprite` of **8 images**. What I want to do is this: if someone hovers over a sub-menu list (let's say item 1), then the sprite image, which is layed on a different div, has to change. So the sub-menu item and this div with the sprite are related to each other by css. The problem is: how do I do this for 8 images?

So this is it:

Hover item 1 =  show sprite image 1

Hover Item 2 = show sprite image 2

Hover Item 3 = show sprite image 3

etc.

Comment: change the background-position on hover?

Comment: background position will not be possible because he is using 8 different images

Comment: @Vivek Dragon What has one to do with the other. Of course is it possible to modify the background position on hovering the item to display another portion of the sprite. In fact this is the most common method in use on thousands of websites…

Comment: @feela Is there any other possibilities other than this?

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this with pure css, when the div is a child of your submenu or a sibling in the DOM.  If not, you have to use javascript for that:

```css
/* child */
.submenu:hover (>) div{}
/*sibling*/
.submenu:hover ~|+ div{}
```

With javascript you need to register a mouseover event to your submenu and change the image in the handler-function.

```
document.queryselector(".submenu").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){/*stuff here*/});
```

The most common way is to change the background-position so another part of your sprite becomes visible. But how to exactly do this, depends on your markup.

Comment: can u give some example link or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I solved it  with background-position. Thanks all.

```
.page-id-1 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -502px 0;}
.page-id-2 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -904px 0;}
 .page-id-3 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -1306px 0;}
.page-id-4 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -1708px 0;}
.page-id-5 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: 0 -71px;}
.page-id-6 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -402px -71px;}
.page-id-7 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -804px -71px;}
.page-id-8 {background: url(images/image.png) top left no-repeat; background-position: -1206px -71px;}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at my fiddle? Was something wrong about that? Btw, you have a lot of redundant css in your declarations... you can omit the background declaration and just put it into one generic block.